# Trying to use NG-CSV with NG-Grid

Tags: angularjs, export-to-csv, ng-grid

I'm trying to use NG-CSV to export data that is displayed with NG-Grid. Currently, my module looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
```

It seems like I should just be able just add the ngCsv dependency inside the [] (given that my html file is properly linked to the ng-csv.js file) like so:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid','ngCsv']);
```

But, every time I try it this way my grid just disappears. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because ngCsv need sanitize, so your angularjs app is break, you see grid disappears.

If you see ngCsv [example](http://jsfiddle.net/asafdav/dR6Nb/), it's work, it is use Angularjs 1.1.5.

If you use AngularJS 1.2.0 and later, you need to add ngSanitize module like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize', 'ngGrid', 'ngCsv']);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AXHrWG24yCgy4sEePwxA?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The export to CSV is an ng-grid plugin, it's not an entire separate module so you do not add it to your Angular dependencies.

Instead, add it to your gridOptions. You also need to make sure the footer's enabled so you can see the button

```
plugins: [new ngGridCsvExportPlugin()],
showFooter: true
```

Comment: Hi seiksng, thank you for your contribution. I am currently using a custom footer for total amounts. I hoping more to put a button outside the grid.